# STL: std::bind1st for std::unary_function

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming, bind

AFAIK `std::bind1st` takes a binary functor and a parameter, and returns an unary functor with already bound first parameter. Does STL provides a function, similar to `std::bind1st`, that takes an unary function and a parameter, and returns a function without parameter?

EDIT: **I need a solution for versions older, than C++11** (I didn't put that tag)

Comment: As of C++11, `std::bind` works in general and so do lambdas.

Comment: `boost::bind`? Boost.Lambda/Boost.Phoenix?

Comment: @chris I need *STL* solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, that STL doesn't provide the solution (`std::bind` is from C++11), so my version is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename Operation>
class bound_unary_function
: public std::unary_function<typename Operation::argument_type,
                             typename Operation::result_type> {
    typedef bound_unary_function<Operation> _Self;

    Operation op;
    typename _Self::argument_type arg;

public:
    bound_unary_function(const Operation& _op, const typename _Self::argument_type& _arg)
    : op(_op), arg(_arg) { }

    typename _Self::result_type operator()() {
        return op(arg);
    }
};

template <typename Operation>
bound_unary_function<Operation> bind_unary_function(const Operation& op,
                                                    const typename Operation::argument_type& arg) {
    return bound_unary_function<Operation>(op, arg);
}

int inc(int x) {
    return ++x;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "inc(0)=" << bind_unary_function(std::ptr_fun(inc), 0)() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The `bind_unary_function` is more convenient, than constructing `bound_unary_function` explicitly, because it features automatic template arguments deduction.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write a binder yourself

```
template<typename FUNCTION, typename ARG_TYPE, typename RETURN_TYPE>
struct bind_it
{
    FUNCTION function;
    ARG_TYPE argument;
    bind_it(ARG_TYPE value, FUNCTION f):function(f){
        argument = value;
    }

    RETURN_TYPE operator()(){
        return function(argument);
    }
};
```

I'm sure there are better ways to write a binder.

And use it like

```
int f(int i){
    return i + 2;
}

int main()
{
    bind_it<int(*)(int), int, int> bound(5, f);
    int se7en = bound();
}
```